# Some emojis not redering properly on Windows broswers

Tags: javascript, windows, emoji

I have this website I am working on. The QA team cut a bug that a emoji (https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%F0%9F%8E%96/) renders as black and white on Windows browsers. On Macs, it renders properly.

Is this bug browser dependent? Or do I need to use some special font in my CSS for Windows machines?

Thanks!

Comment: i don't see it at all in chrome on windows...

Comment: Many emojis don't render properly on Windows machines it seems.

Comment: guess it depends on many things ... latest windows 10 fall creators update + **any browser** ... colourful medal ... which version of Windows are you specifically having the issue with

Comment: i would not rely on emojis for UI. you often times can't even predict the color on a given platform, which can lead to poor contrast. use a custom-font-based solution for maximum repeat-ability
 w/o distro headaches.

Comment: Looks like I'll apply validations to reject emojis in the first place.

Comment: The emoji is properly rendered in Windows. Emojis just look different in different platforms, there's nothing you can do to change this. Ex. see https://emojipedia.org/grinning-face/ Which is the proper happy face?

Comment: @Teemu But the thing is, none of the grinning faces is in grey scale.

Comment: It's not a thing, stop supporting IE, and you will be released from the pain. Hmm... I'm barking a wrong tree, I can see Military Medal in colors in IE too ...